# How to make views aligned on any device in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Just started messing around with Android studio for the first time. When I put text or a button on the test device it will be centered , but if I switch to a phone or tablet with a different size screen it's un-centered. On the tutorial I am watching his will stay centered on an Any advice on how to fix this?

app on phone size display:

[image]

app on tablet size display:

[image]

Comment: Please share layout file

Comment: show your `XML` code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add *constraints* to your `Button` in order to make sure that it's centered on every device. To do this, constrain the button's left edge to the parent's left edge, and constrain the button's right edge to the parent's right edge.

To do this in the layout editor, click and hold on the little dot on either side of your `Button`, and then drag that dot to the parent's edge. This will add the constraint for you.

Alternatively, you can add constraints in the xml. In this case, you would add these:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layout_gravity center` or `center horizontal`, but you can add your own layout for tablet(you must add tablet layout to folder `layout-large`)

Comment: You should try to provide small *code-snippets* of what you feel will resolve the issue. This will aid the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test app"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BUTTON"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Added **left** and **right** constraints to `TextView` and `Button` to **parent's** **left** and **right** respectively so that it will be aligned middle horizontally wrt parent(screen).
Also added button top constraint to **bottom** of `TextView` so that `Button` will be aligned below `TextView`

Comment: Explain your answer, give reasons. Don't just put your code here and encourage him to copy-paste